# Localization with separate Language folders within Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, view, routes

I'm trying to have specific folders for each language in Views. (I know this isn't the best way of doing it but it has to be this way for now)
e.g. 
`/Views/EN/User/Edit.aspx`
`/Views/US/User/Edit.aspx`

These would both use the same controller and model but have different Views for each language.

In my `Global.asax.cs` I have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { language = "en", controller = "Logon", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
    new { language = @"en|us" } // validation
);
```

This works ok but always points to the same View.
If I put the path to the Lanagugage folder it works:

```
return View("~/Views/EN/User/Edit.aspx");
```

But clearly this isn't a very nice way to do it.
Is there anyway to get MVC to look in the correct language folder?

I know this isn't the best way of doing Localization but I can't use resource files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the ViewEngine to use a routeparameter

[Change lookup rule for views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639450/change-lookup-rule-for-views)

**EDIT**

Since the list of paths scanned for the view is static there is no chance to choose different views depending on some controller instance by working changing the list according to the link above.
This looks a more promissing starting point:

http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/01/31/ASPNET-MVC-e28093-Dynamically-Changing-The-Master-Page-%28Theming%29.aspx

It overwrites CreateView to chnage the view rendered. The sample changes the Masterpage, but hopefully it also works for views.

Comment: That looks spot on but how do I get the {language} from the Route Table/URL?

Comment: Needed to change the ViewPath and leave the master but works really well.
Thanks for the help.